# Jooq- Updating a field to NULL makes it "null" and not NULL

Tags: jooq

So this was my query that previously worked in jooq 3.11.

I am updating a JSON field, however it is mapped to a String in my model using a JsonBinding which I will post down below

```
        dsl.update(TASK)
            .set(TASK.JSON_SOLUTION, (String) null).            
        .where(TASK.TENANT.eq(getCurrentTenant()))
        .and(TASK.TASK_TEMPLATE_ID.in(taskTemplateIds));execute()
```

This now no longer works after upgrading to jooq 3.13.2. I also had to change my sql dialect to be mysql even though I am working with a mysql 5_7 database, this may be the issue?

I have also tried this and it is still the same

```
        dsl.update(TASK)
            .setNull(TASK.JSON_SOLUTION).            
         .where(TASK.TENANT.eq(getCurrentTenant()))
        .and(TASK.TASK_TEMPLATE_ID.in(taskTemplateIds));execute()
```

JsonBinding.class

```
public class JsonBinding implements Binding<JSON, String> {

  @Override
  public Converter<JSON, String> converter() {
    return new JsonConverter();
  }

  @Override
  public void sql(BindingSQLContext<String> bindingSQLContext) {
    if (bindingSQLContext.render().paramType() == ParamType.INLINED) {
      bindingSQLContext
          .render()
          .visit(DSL.inline(bindingSQLContext.convert(converter()).value()))
          .sql("::json");
    } else {
      bindingSQLContext.render().sql("?");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void register(BindingRegisterContext<String> bindingRegisterContext) throws SQLException {
    bindingRegisterContext
        .statement()
        .registerOutParameter(bindingRegisterContext.index(), Types.VARCHAR);
  }

  @Override
  public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<String> bindingSetStatementContext)
      throws SQLException {
    bindingSetStatementContext
        .statement()
        .setString(
            bindingSetStatementContext.index(),
            Objects.toString(bindingSetStatementContext.convert(converter()).value(), null));
  }

  @Override
  public void set(BindingSetSQLOutputContext<String> bindingSetSQLOutputContext)
      throws SQLException {
    throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
  }

  @Override
  public void get(BindingGetResultSetContext<String> bindingGetResultSetContext)
      throws SQLException {
    bindingGetResultSetContext
        .convert(converter())
        .value(
            JSON.valueOf(
                bindingGetResultSetContext
                    .resultSet()
                    .getString(bindingGetResultSetContext.index())));
  }

  @Override
  public void get(BindingGetStatementContext<String> bindingGetStatementContext)
      throws SQLException {
    bindingGetStatementContext
        .convert(converter())
        .value(
            JSON.valueOf(
                bindingGetStatementContext
                    .statement()
                    .getString(bindingGetStatementContext.index())));
  }

  @Override
  public void get(BindingGetSQLInputContext<String> bindingGetSQLInputContext) throws SQLException {
    throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
  }
}
```

JsonConverter.class

```
public class JsonConverter implements Converter<JSON, String> {

  @Override
  public String from(JSON object) {
    return object != null ? object.toString() : null;
  }

  @Override
  public JSON to(String string) {
    return JSON.valueOf(string);
  }

  @Override
  public Class<JSON> fromType() {
    return JSON.class;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<String> toType() {
    return String.class;
  }
}
```

Here is the query jooq runs with .setNull()

```
update `tasks_service`.`task` set `tasks_service`.`task`.`json_solution` = 'null'::json where (`tasks_service`.`task`.`tenant` = 'skynet' and `tasks_service`.`task`.`task_template_id` in ('55', '33'))
```

Before the upgrade on jooq 3.11 the query comes out as this

```
update `tasks_service`.`task` set `tasks_service`.`task`.`json_solution` = null::json where (`tasks_service`.`task`.`tenant` = 'skynet' and `tasks_service`.`task`.`task_template_id` in ('55', '33'))
```

So before its set 'json_solution' = null and after the upgrade it seems to be set 'json_solution' = 'null'

Not quite sure why this is occurring?

Edit: So from what I can tell this solely  seems to be from the upgrade in JOOQ and not the sql-dialect. Using Jooq 3.11.5 with both mysql and mysql_5_7 as the dialects, the query is built as set 'json_solution' = null, if I upgrade JOOQ to 3.13.2 its set 'json_solution' = 'null'

This quirk also seems to only happen on the JSON field, I tried setting another varchar String field to be null on the same table, and I get the correct set "field_name' = null

The problem may be with my JsonBinding/JsonConverter ? I had to modify it slightly to work with the new JSON object in JOOQ, as previously JOOQ mapped JSON as Object

Comment: how does the executed SQL look like?

Comment: Updated OP with query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `JSON.valueOf(null)` vs `(JSON) null`

The answer is in the Javadoc of [`org.jooq.JSON`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/JSON.html):

> A `CAST(NULL AS JSON)` value is represented by a `null` reference of type `JSON`, not as `data() == null`. This is consistent with jOOQ's general way of returning `NULL` from `Result` and `Record` methods.

So, the mistake is in `JsonConverter`'s usage of [`JSON.valueOf()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/JSON.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)). Write this instead:

```java
  public JSON to(String string) {
    return string == null ? null : JSON.valueOf(string);
  }
```

Or, just use [`Converter.ofNullable()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Converter.html#ofNullable(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Class,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)), which handles the null-to-null mapping for you:

```
Converter<JSON, String> converter = Converter.ofNullable(
  JSON.class,
  String.class,
  JSON::data,
  JSON::json
);
```

#### Side note on using a `Binding`

You don't really need the binding anymore, now that the `JSON` type is suppported natively by jOOQ. If you want to convert `JSON` to `String`, your `Converter` will be sufficient.

Comment: I made that first change and i get the query update `tasks_service`.`task` set `tasks_service`.`task`.`json_solution` = null::json where (`tasks_service`.`task`.`tenant` = 'skynet' and `tasks_service`.`task`.`task_template_id` in ('55', '33'))
2020-08-13 08:57:44.403 DEBUG 10058 --- [           main] org.jooq.tools.LoggerListener            : Affected row(s)          : 2

Comment: However it is still set as "null" in the DB and not NULL

Comment: I can copy and paste the query into my DB and it works as intended, however jooq seems to set it as "null"

Comment: @HelloWhatsMyName1234: The difference you're observing is due to the fact that you're copy pasting the debug log output, which contains inline bind values (where you cast to json explicitly), whereas jOOQ executes a prepared statement. Are you still using your custom binding? I didn't check the entirety of it, because I assumed you'd drop it. For example, I suspect that this is wrong: `sql("?")`. You'd need to cast your bind value as `?::json`

Comment: So I do have ::json just above that in the binding. I set both the if/else statement parts to be ?::json and I actually seem to get Sql syntax exceptions. How would I stop using the binding and still have the same implicit behaviours I use now? Right now in my pom for the generator  i have the following

Comment: <forcedTypes>
                <forcedType>
                  <userType>String</userType>
                  <binding>api.task.repo.json.JsonBinding</binding>
                  <expression>.*JSON.*</expression>
                  <types>.*JSON.*</types>
                </forcedType>
              </forcedTypes>

Comment: I know that I could just use the JOOQ.JSON object, but I still want to bind it to a string implicitly like it currently does, changing the object to JOOQ.JSON would be alot of changes in the codebase I am trying to avoid

Comment: just replace the `<binding/>` specification by `<converter>api.task.repo.json.JsonConverter</converter>`, or whatever package that is in. I'd have to try to reproduce the binding issues, but starting from when `JSON` types were supported, it was unlikely that anyone would still use a binding for JSON types, unless you really *need* to bind the type manually via some esoteric JDBC API calls.